# Subscriber-only acceptor port in ActiveMQ - is it possible?

Tags: activemq-classic, activemq-artemis

We want to use Apache ActiveMQ (either "Classic" or Artemis) as a WebSocket server sending update notifications to Internet clients via STOMP. For this to work safely, we need to configure an `acceptor` so that it would be unable to publish anything, and only able to subscribe to a named topic(s); the events on the topic would originate from the internal network. None of the external subscribers will be permanent.

As I understand, this filtering has to be done at the application level, as even just subscribing to an address requires two-way traffic.

I found a guide on how to rate-limit a producer in [ActiveMQ "Classic"](https://activemq.apache.org/producer-flow-control) and in [ActiveMQ Artemis](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/flow-control), but it's not exactly what we want to achieve - we want this particular `acceptor` to be unable to publish at all.

I would appreciate a pointer towards a solution for both ActiveMQ "Classic" and for ActiveMQ Artemis.

Comment: The subscribers will be using WebSocket exclusively.

Comment: I'm told it'll be STOMP.

Comment: I will. Both solutions seem to address our problem, just let me test them. We're now working on making the Artemis solution work, as this is the setup we already have. ActiveMQ 5 is next. Give us a week or so, ok?

Answer (score 0):

ActiveMQ 5.x can do this!

On the transportConnector you want set 'maximumProducersAllowedPerConnection=0':

```
<transportConnector uri="nio://0.0.0.0:61616" maximumProducersAllowedPerConnection="0" ../>
```

Clients will get this exception:

```
Caused by: javax.jms.JMSException: Can't add producer on connection ID:broker-62244-1682603624916-4:1: at maximum limit: 0
```

Answer (score -1):

As Matt noted, you can do this in ActiveMQ "Classic" by setting (the apparently undocumented) `maximumProducersAllowedPerConnection=0` on the relevant `transportConnector`.

In ActiveMQ Artemis you'd enforce this via [security](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/security.html). In your case, the role for the "Internet clients" would only allow subscribing on specific topics and would *not* allow sending at all. Say all your "Internet clients" were logging in with credentials belonging to the role `internetClients` your `security-settings` in `broker.xml` might look something like this:

```xml
      <security-settings>
         <security-setting match="myTopic">
            <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="internetClients"/>
            <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="internetClients"/>
            <permission type="consume" roles="internetClients"/>
         </security-setting>
      </security-settings>
```

The `createNonDurableQueue` and `deleteNonDurableQueue` permissions will allow the clients to create a subscription on the topic and the `consume` permission will allow them to receive messages from their subscription queues. The `match` value of `myTopic` means that these settings apply to the address named `myTopic` although you can add more `security-setting` blocks or expand the match using a [wildcard](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/wildcard-syntax.html).

Comment: ActiveMQ 5.x can do this!

Comment: My apologies! I didn't find `maximumProducersAllowedPerConnection` in the documentation when I looked. I updated my answer based on this.